# Plot an IPython Notebook figure inline with fig.show()?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm calling the inline mode for IPython Notebook using;

```
%pylab inline
```

And the following code plots a figure immediately at the cell;

```
fig = plt.figure()
axes = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
```

However I would like to create the plot/axes etc. in one cell, and plot later using maybe;

```
fig.show()
```

How do I gain more control of the inline mode? If I don't use %pylab inline, it creates the plot in a seperate window which I don't want (and it usually freezes the window).

Versions;

```
Numpy: 1.7.0
Matplotlib: 1.2.1rc1
Python: 2.7.2 (default, Jun 24 2011, 12:22:14) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
Pandas: 0.10.1
PyLab: 1.7.0
```

Comment: Have you tried with the display function of Ipython? it is the "ufficial" method, as far as I know

Comment: Is it that you don't want the figure generated, or you just don't want to look at the empty axes?

Comment: In general, I want to create a figure in one cell, work on it say in another using it's handle, and hold off on displaying it until yet a different cell later on.

Comment: If either of the two answers posted solve you problem, please accept it (big check mark on the left).

Answer (score 7):

So I guess what you want is this:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as fc
fig = Figure()
canvas = fc(fig)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot(arange(10))
```

To display the plot in another cell simply use:

```
fig
```

Comment: Thanx tor the answer. This also means that display(fig) will do it.

Answer (score 5):

You might be looking for disabling autoclose figure :

```
InlineBackend options
---------------------
--InlineBackend.close_figures=<CBool>
    Default: True
Close all figures at the end of each cell.
When True, ensures that each cell starts with no active figures, but it also
means that one must keep track of references in order to edit or redraw
figures in subsequent cells. This mode is ideal for the notebook, where
residual plots from other cells might be surprising.
When False, one must call figure() to create new figures. This means that
gcf() and getfigs() can reference figures created in other cells, and the
active figure can continue to be edited with pylab/pyplot methods that
reference the current active figure. This mode facilitates iterative editing
of figures, and behaves most consistently with other matplotlib backends,
but figure barriers between cells must be explicit.
```

still, IPython  will show the figure if the last line of a cell return a fig object, you can avoid that by ending it with a `;` or add `pass` as the last line.

Comment: c.InlineBackend.close_figures = False is now set in \myIPythonDir\profile_myHomeProfile\ipython_notebook_config.py. The axes = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1]) cmd still gives me a plot after the cell, even with semicolon and pass. Any way to view current options to check if this flag is indeed set?

Comment: `%config InlineBackend` should tell you the different config value.

Comment: This one almost works! I just can't get the figures to surpress in the intermediate cells i.e. with ; or pass

Comment: set matplotlib interactive to false ? `matplotlib.ioff()` IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

With newer [jupyter](/questions/tagged/jupyter) and [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib)

- Jupyter: 4.6
- Jupyter notebook: 6.0
- Matplotlib: 3.1
- ipykernel: 5.1

all you really need is to create your figure with `matplotlib.pyplot.Figure` (in one cell) and then make that figure the cell value in another cell.  For example

In cell `[1]`

```
%matplotlib inline
```

In cell `[2]`

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import Figure
from numpy import arange 
from numpy.random import normal 

fig = Figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(arange(10),normal(size=10),label='Data')
ax.set_xlabel('$x$')
ax.set_ylabel('$y$')
ax.legend();
```

and finally in cell `[3]`

```
fig
```

That should be enough.   See the screenshot below

[image: Screenshot]

Note suggestions with `matplotlib.pyplot.ioff()` and similar does not work