# prevent plot from showing in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, figures

How can I prevent a specific plot to be shown in Jupyter notebook? I have several plots in a notebook but I want a subset of them to be saved to a file and not shown on the notebook as this slows considerably.

A minimal working example for a Jupyter notebook is:

```
%matplotlib inline 
from numpy.random import randn
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, figure
a=randn(3)
b=randn(3)
for i in range(10):
    fig=figure()
    plot(b)
    fname='s%03d.png'%i
    fig.savefig(fname)
    if(i%5==0):
        figure()
        plot(a)
```

As you can see I have two types of plots, a and b. I want a's to be plotted and shown and I don't want the b plots to be shown, I just want them them to be saved in a file. Hopefully this will speed things a bit and won't pollute my notebook with figures I don't need to see.

Thank you for your time

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plot an IPython Notebook figure inline with fig.show()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480379/plot-an-ipython-notebook-figure-inline-with-fig-show)

Comment: honestly, I didn't understand the answers on that question

Comment: For more info and similar issue, look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713279/calling-pylab-savefig-without-display-in-ipython

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Perhaps just clear the axis, for example:

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(range(10))
fig.savefig("save_file_name.pdf")
plt.close()
```

This will not plot the output in `inline` mode. I can't work out if it is really clearing the data though.

Comment: It does not plot the output but returns <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x31c0d50> how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I have updated the answer, using `plt.close()` doesn't output this. I think it is some kind of reference to the figure left over but I'm not sure.

Comment: This is subtle, but changing `plt.close()` to `plt.close();` should do the trick.  This worked for me on IPython 2 and matplotlib 1.3.1

Comment: In my case, using `notebook` mode, this method still creates some empty space in the output cell, which clutters my notebook when doing multiple plots at once. I wrapped my plotting routine in a pair of `plt.ioff()` and `plt.ion()` and now there is no more clutter.

Comment: Documentation link: [matplotlib.pyplot.close — Matplotlib 3.2.1 documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.close.html)

Answer (score 58):

I was able to prevent my figures from displaying by turning interactive mode off using the function

> plt.ioff()

Comment: Very helpful if you're using mpld3 (or something similar) for making interactive online figures and `%matplotlib notebook` to preview static figures.

Comment: @Brian Why should this be the new accepted answer? How is this method better than the previous? Is it more general?

Answer (score 47):

To prevent any output from a jupyter notebook cell you may start the cell with

```
%%capture
```

This might be usefull in cases all other methods shown here fail.

Comment: This is the best answer by far.

Comment: How would this be done in a jupyter-lab notebook running R?  I get a Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:1:1: unexpected SPECIAL       1: %%

Comment: I guess if there are errors, you have to switch it on and off

Answer (score 20):

From IPython 6.0 on, there is another option to turn the inline output off (temporarily or persistently). This has been introduced [in this pull request](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/9916).

You would use the "agg" backend to not show any inline output.

```
%matplotlib agg
```

It seems though that if you had activated the inline backend first, this needs to be called twice to take effect.

```
%matplotlib agg
%matplotlib agg
```

Here is how it would look in action

[image]

Comment: Do you know why agg needs to be called twice if inline was already called?

Answer (score 10):

On Jupyter 6.0, I use the following snippet to selectively not display the matplot lib figures.

```
import matplotlib as mpl

...

backend_ =  mpl.get_backend() 
mpl.use("Agg")  # Prevent showing stuff

# Your code

mpl.use(backend_) # Reset backend
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm a beginner though,off the inline mode when you don't want to see the output in your notebook by:

```
%matplotlib auto
```

or:

```
%matplotlib
```

to use it back:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

more better solution would be to use:

```
plt.ioff()
```

which says inline mode off.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Building off @importanceofbeingernest's answer, one may call some function in a loop, and at each iteration, want to render a plot. However, between the each plot, you may want to render additional stuff.

Concretely:

1. Iterate a list of IDs
2. Call a function so a plot is rendered for each "ID"
3. Between each plot, render some markdown

---

```
# <cell begins>
def render(id):
   fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1)
   plt.suptitle(f'Metrics for {id}')

   df.ColA.plot.bar(ax=axes[0])
   df.ColB.plot.bar(ax=axes[1])

   return fig

# <cell ends>

# -------------------------------------

# <cell begins>
%matplotlib agg

for id in df.ID.value_counts().index:
   fig = render(id)

   display(fig)
   display(Markdown('---'))

# <cell ends>
```