# Why matplotlib does not show the scatter plot in a second cell of a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, scatter-plot

I'm drawing scatter plot in jupyter notebook which contains 2 cells

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Plot single point
# 1st, create a figure
fig = plt.figure()
# then create an 'ax' in this figure
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
# plot red point at x=7, y=42
ax.scatter(x = [7], y = [42])
```

and

```
# Plot multiple points
# create a center
center = (7, 42)
# sample scaled normal distribution
datapoints = 10 * np.random.randn(50, 50)
# re-center data
datapoints[0, :] += center[0]
datapoints[1, :] += center[1]
# plot red point for every data-point
ax.scatter(x = datapoints[0, :], y = datapoints[1, :], color = "red")
plt.show()
```

The first cell returns

[image]

whereas the second one returns nothing. Could you please elaborate on this problem?

**Update:** I tried to put

```
ax
fig
```

in the second cell. In particular,

```
# Plot multiple points
# create a center
center = (7, 42)
# sample scaled normal distribution
datapoints = 10 * np.random.randn(50, 50)
# re-center data
datapoints[0, :] += center[0]
datapoints[1, :] += center[1]
# plot red point for every data-point
ax
fig
ax.scatter(x = datapoints[0, :], y = datapoints[1, :], color = "red")
plt.show()
```

But running second cell still returns nothing.

Comment: @Mr.T Thank you for adding the tag `jupyter-notebook`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I show the same matplotlib figure several times in a single IPython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265987/how-do-i-show-the-same-matplotlib-figure-several-times-in-a-single-ipython-noteb)

Comment: @user202729 please see my update.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? What's the behavior? (nothing show up?)

Comment: @user202729 Update corrected. Nothing shows up.

Comment: I think that the description of the "edit" is not very clear (you might edit it incorrectly), can that be clarified?

Comment: @user202729 Sorry for this inconvenience, I've clarified it.

Comment: I mean, where exactly did you put `ax` and `fig` into the second cell?

Comment: @user202729 I put both of them right before `ax.scatter(x = datapoints[0, :], y = datapoints[1, :], color = "red")`.

Comment: @user202729 I've just added the second cell after adding `ax` and `fig`.

Comment: you have to put `fig` at the last line. (explanation later)

Comment: Thank you so much @user202729. Now it works. I will write clearer description for later questions.

Comment: I posted an explanation to the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Plot multiple points
# create a center
center = (7, 42)
# sample scaled normal distribution
datapoints = 10 * np.random.randn(50, 50)
# re-center data
datapoints[0, :] += center[0]
datapoints[1, :] += center[1]
```

in this code you added numbers to the X and y numbers which may made your values out of the size of your plt window.
try using:

```
plt.ylim([0,100])
plt.xlim([0,15])
```

Good luck!

Edit : I also tried your code and it works fine with me when i put both cells into one cell :

[image]

Comment: there's also [python - Automatically Rescale ylim and xlim in Matplotlib - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984085/automatically-rescale-ylim-and-xlim-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Your solution does not work. It only shows a blank plot.

Comment: But that's not it. OP said "nothing shows up", not "the old plot show up without any red point".

Comment: Did you put all the code in just 1 cell, or 2 separate cells (as I did)?

Comment: Ahmed, "your code works for me" is not an answer. You two should not describe in more detail the presets of your Jupyter notebooks to find out what the difference is that causes the different behavior.

Comment: i mean it worked fine as the plot shows that i am running both cells together in one cell.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you create the figure at the same cell where you want to show the plot.
If those two plots should be independent, just add following line at the beginning of second cell:

```
# creates figure and axis in one command without any additional settings
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

Or put the `ax.scatter()` calls into the same cell if you want these scatters to be in the same axis.