# How to prevent matplotlib from to showing a figure even with plt.close() in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, tensorboard

I create a matplotlib figure within my neural network training loop for creating a Tensorboard image. Therefore, I use `plot_to_image()` to convert the figure to an image as mentioned in [the official Tensorboard guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/image_summaries).

```
def plot_to_image(figure):
    """Converts the matplotlib plot specified by 'figure' to a PNG image and
    returns it. The supplied figure is closed and inaccessible after this call."""
    # Save the plot to a PNG in memory.
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
    # Closing the figure prevents it from being displayed directly inside the notebook.
    plt.close(figure)
    buf.seek(0)
    # Convert PNG buffer to TF image
    image = tf.image.decode_png(buf.getvalue(), channels=3)
    # Add the batch dimension
    image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)
    return image


for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    # ...
    # error_fig = >some fancy plt.fig for visualizing stuff in Tensorboard<
    tf.summary.image(name='train_error_img', data=plot_to_image(error_fig), step=epoch)
    print('Some metrics for this particular epoch..')
    # ...
```

The `plt.close(figure)` should prevent the figure to be shown. However, in my jupyter notebook, I get an empty space in my output between the print statements.  If I highlight the output, I can even see the three images I create for each epoch as a blank space (Yes, I call the function three different times for one epoch for different figures).

[image]

My question now is:
How can I change this behaviour but still get my print statement shown?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You might try plt.figure(figsize=(0,0)) before closing the fig.  Hacky but simple.

Comment: Similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717877/prevent-plot-from-showing-in-jupyter-notebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve my problem by using `plt.ioff()` at the start of my training routine and `plt.ion()` at the end. The answer was given in a comment of the question linked by @TFer. Thanks!