# Matplotlib GUI showing even though I never called plt.show()

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, matplotlib-widget, savefig

I am using the following functions in order...

```
 - plt.figure()
 - plt.plot()
 - plt.ylim 
 - plt.xticks() 
 - figure = plt.gcf() 
 - figure.set_size_inches()
 - plt.savefig()
```

I just want to save the figure as png, which I've been doing successfully. But the GUI keeps showing up and I am going to generate a bunch of graphs in one script, I don't want the GUI popping up every time one is created and slow my run time.

Does anyone know why it is showing up still?

Comment: Jonah, did my answer below solve your problem? If so, please kindly mark it as such. Thanks.

Comment: I responded to your answer. It has not helped me unfortunately

Comment: I don't have any more ideas. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Jupyter Notebook, there are a number of potential solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717877/prevent-plot-from-showing-in-jupyter-notebook).

To summarize, try this to disable inline output from Matplotlib:

```py
import matplotlib as plt
plt.ioff()
```

Or put this at the start of a cell to prevent it from creating output:

```py
%%capture
```

Comment: I'm using PyCharm as an IDE. I've tried plt.ioff() and it hasn't worked in the past.

Comment: You have to use plt.ioff() after the first plot, otherwise it will still show the images.